# Can't restore disabled iPhone because not enough disk space

Tags: iphone

I am trying to restore a disabled iPhone 4s so my daughter can use it but iTunes gives the error not enough disk space. Obviously I can't delete anything from the phone because it's disabled. Is there any way to clear up storage space while disabled?

Comment: "Not enough disk space"... Are you sure iTunes is not complaining about the computer its running on?  I don't see how iOS will ever warn about "disk" space.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting it to iTunes, I would choose to set it up as a new device, rather than restoring from a backup.

Once you've done that then do the restore on your iPhone from the backup you wanted to use.

**NOTE:** Ensure that you do not do a new backup of your iPhone 4s before doing the restore. You may want to make a backup of your iPhone 4s backup before you begin, just in case. If you're not sure of where the backups are located, refer to this [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215).

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that you do not want to use any of the content already on the iPhone, you can place it into Recovery Mode and have iTunes restore it. Make sure that you have the Apple ID and password of the account that was on the phone before following the steps below otherwise you will still be unable to use the device.

1. Plug your iPhone in to your computer and ensure iTunes is open and can recognise the device.
2. Press and hold both power and home buttons at the same time until the screen goes black.
3. Continue holding both buttons for 4 seconds after the screen goes black.
4. Release the power button and continue holding the home button until iTunes recognises it.

The device will be recognised as "in recovery mode" and iTunes will give you the option to restore it. iTunes will then download the most recent software for that device and restore it, wiping the device and displaying the first-time setup for iOS.